# React JSX expression for className is not evaluated at runtime

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I have the following template with the expression for the `className` property that I expect to be evaluated every time React calls the `render` method:

```
<ul className='ratings' onClick={this.handleClick}>
    <li className={'fa-star ' + (this.rating > 0) ? 'fas' : 'far'}></li>
</ul>
```

I expect it to be converted to this and this actually what [online Babel transpiler shows](https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=DwVwNgBAxmCGDO8BysC2BTAvAcgE6wBcBLAOwHN5sIB7EgYTCKgGtMBvAgCyPgDpPYJACZh0DJswC-APgBQEBRGCNocRCgztsAM1gBaeAVi4IVANQQAFFx698xchGkQADAEoIAflO7KEAFw-xtgywAD0jHLh4NJAA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=):

```
React.createElement(
    'ul',
    { className: 'ratings', onClick: this.handleClick },

    React.createElement('li', { 
        'data-value': '1', 
        className: 'fa-star ' + (this.rating > 0) ? 'fas' : 'far' 
    })
);
```

I'm using create-react-app starter. And when I debug it I see the following:

```
createElement('li', { 
    'data-value': '1', className:  true ? 'fas' : 'far', 
    ...
})
```

It's like the expression is being evaluated during build time. What am I missing?

Comment: Put parens around the ternary. Playing in the console makes the immediately obvious. (Unrelated, but prefer string interpolation, and newer React, if possible.)

Comment: @DaveNewton, yes, I got confused by JSX syntax. Yeah, I use string interpolation everyday in JS, I'll use it here as well. What about newer React?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com Oh, sorry, you're showing the transpiled JSX; I misunderstood.

Comment: @DaveNewton, no worries, thanks. It's interesting that online babel showed expected result even with incorrect parenthesis, I guess that what confused me

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar, see what, sorry? The problem is misplaced parenthesis

Comment: I'm not talking about the issue. You got its solution. But I'm asking if we can see the transpiled JSX in local project you stated earlier by debugging. How can we debug? Just a little bit curious.

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com Not sure what you mean by "expected result"; the conversion has a bug because of the missing parens. That's the source. Depending on how you're debugging (and likely the browser) there's been operations taking place already either by the browser, the JS runtime, or magic, so . you see the results of the ternary's expression.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar, I just put the "debugger" statement in the `render` method and opened Dev Tools. There you can see the transpiled result

Comment: @DaveNewton, I believe it's some optimizer like UglifyJs inside the `react-create-app` build chain evaluated it in runtime. JSX probably left it as is

Comment: Ah, I've never noticed that. Thanks.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is operator precedence. `'fa-star ' + (this.rating > 0)` is evaluated as ternary condition and is always true.

It should be:

```
<li className={'fa-star ' + (this.rating > 0 ? 'fas' : 'far')}></li>
```

A convenient helper for class joining is [`classnames`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames):

```
<li className={classnames('fa-star', { fas: !!this.rating, far: !this.rating })}></li>
```